# Send soap xml data in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Please how can I send the following xml to a remote webservice(****/quick.svc?wsdl) using soap in php

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:quic="http://services.interswitchng.com/quicktellerservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <quic:SendBillPaymentAdvice>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <quic:xmlParams>
         <![CDATA[<BillPaymentAdvice>
    <Amount>10000</Amount>
    <PaymentCode>145536</PaymentCode>
    <CustomerMobile>0856534</CustomerMobile>
    <CustomerEmail>luvysols@gmail.com</CustomerEmail>
    <CustomerId>Trdfg001</CustomerId>
    <TerminalId>2323001</TerminalId>
    <RequestReference>123456789</RequestReference>
    </BillPaymentAdvice>]]>
         </quic:xmlParams>
      </quic:SendBillPaymentAdvice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SoapClient class provides a client for `SOAP 1.1`, `SOAP 1.2` servers. It can be used in WSDL or non-WSDL mode.

```
$url         = "";
$client     = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Just wanna send my request in that format. I've gone thru the manual but its just to bulky!

Answer (score 0):

First Include the `nusoap.php` and after it add this code.

```
$sen_code='XML CODE';
$client->debug($headers,$sen_code);
$client->decode_utf8 = FALSE;
$rel_lgoin = $client->call('method_for_call');
```